# S3::inputFile(): Unable to open input file( input file from s3 bucket only)

Tags: php, amazon-s3

Am trying file upload to s3 bucket in php.

1) First am uploading image(ex:xyz.jpg) to `mybucket/temp` folder(temp folder is in s3 bucket only).

2) Then from temp folder am trying to move to `mybucket/upload` folder.

Here am using

```
$blnReturn = S3::putObject(S3::inputFile($strSourcePath), 'assets.mydomain.com', $strS3DestinationPath, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);
(Here $strSourcePath = "//assets.mydomain.com/static/temp/xyz.jpg";
$strS3DestinationPath = "//assets.mydomain.com/static/upload/2_xyz.jpg")
```

Now am getting:

`S3::inputFile(): Unable to open input file: //assets.mydomain.com/static/temp/xyz.jpg.`

Any solutions.?

Note:

1) Source path exists.

2) I dont want to use copy and move methods. because need to create three images with one image

Comment: Are you using the command line or a programming language?

Comment: programming language

Comment: Which one? Provide as much context as you can in order to get the best answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same error and in my case the error was due to upload_max_filesize limit on my server. You can modify php.ini file to change the value

```
post_max_size = 16M
upload_max_filesize = 16M
memory_limit = 128M
```

or you can modify .htaccess file.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 16M
php_value post_max_size 16M
```

This will work only if the AllowOverride settings permit it. I hope this might help you.

Comment: Good catch. It really helped :)